# Visual Studio Team Services - Restrict access by IP address?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-active-directory, azure-devops

Has anyone successfully restricted Visual Studio Team Services access by IP address? The following blog post says it is possible by connecting the VS Team Services with Azure AD.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/06/25/azure-ad-conditional-access-preview-update-more-apps-and-blocking-access-for-users-not-at-work/

> After signing up will see the Visual Studio Team Services application on the application tab of the Azure AD portal. You can then go to the application's configure tab and set access rules, just like you would for other applications. (Like the Twitter example above.)

I have connected Team Services with Azure AD, but when I go in the Azure AD portal, click on applications under my domain and then click on "Visual Studio Online" all I get is a "Dashboard" with usage graphs. There is no "Configure" tab as the blog post says there should be. I have backed my Team Services account with TFS. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Think I found the issue. In the below link it says:

> These capabilities will be available to customers that have purchased an Azure Active Directory Premium license.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-conditional-access-azuread-connected-apps/

Since I'm not subscribed to Azure AD Premium that is most likely why I don't get the configuration tab and the option to restrict access by IP address. Some what annoying that you would have to pay for Azure AD Premium access to get such a standard feature when already paying for VS Team Services.

Comment: r u able to achieve this? I am also looking for the same access restriction.Anything changed for VS team services since this question is 2 yrs old.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the AD: [azure-ad-conditional-access-preview-update-more-apps-and-blocking-access-for-users-not-at-work](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/06/25/azure-ad-conditional-access-preview-update-more-apps-and-blocking-access-for-users-not-at-work/):

> Blocking external access
>
> In other cases only users on the corporate network may be allowed to
>   access a SaaS application. This rule can help prevent data leakage and
>   in some cases can help you meet regulatory requirements.
>
> When an app is on-premises you would have easily been able enforce
>   this policy at your network boundary. With the app in the cloud this
>   becomes more challenging.
>
> We've helped address by adding the block access when not at work rule.
>   This rule can be applied to any of your Azure AD applications that
>   support conditional access.
>
> The page below shows the option on the same Twitter configure tab as
>   above.
>
> When you choose this option only users coming from an IP address that
>   falls within an IP range you have identified will be allowed access to
>   the application.

Comment: Yep, that is the blog entry I followed. The problem is I don't see any "Configure" tab for Visual Studio Online under the AD portal. Only the dashboard with usage graphs.

Comment: You have to connect your vsts to your ad: `Connect your Visual Studio Team Services account to Azure Active Directory so people in your organization can sign in. To do this, you must be the account owner and a directory member. Before you connect, add your users to the directory so they don’t lose account access. Learn More...` You can do this in the main item vsts -> configure

Comment: Yep, I did that before posting. If I go under the configure menu of Visual Studio Team Services in the classic Azure Portal it shows VS Online is connected to Azure AD: **Your account is connected to your subscription's Azure Active Directory. This means all account users must be directory members to access your account. Only directory administrators can add directory members.**