# Visual studio online IP restriction in VM not working

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, virtual-machine

I want to provide/restrict access to resources based on IP from my google cloud vm to prevent my dev team downloading/uploading the code to public drives.

Everything is working fine up to now.But I want to provide access to Visual studio online TFS with my outlook account.

I created visual studio online account for  Version control.
URL: https://eschooltest.visualstudio.com
Region: Canada Central

I came to know vs online IPs are published every wednesday and downloaded from the below url and added these canada central Ips to Google Firewall system with allow access.

https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/ip-addresses-used-hosted-build/

But still I am not able to access vs url.I pinged this url from command prompt and found the ip is **13.107.6.175** which is not present in the canada central IP list and also not present in the whole ip list of all regions.

Can someone help to achieve the requirement? OR please let me know if there is an elegant way of doing this.

if this is not possible with VS online, I am planning to set up TFS express in another VM to prevent leaking of my code to outside world though this is cumbersome.

EDIT: 
1. Why this ip is not present in the Published xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Team Services - Restrict access by IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654707/visual-studio-team-services-restrict-access-by-ip-address)

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for the reply. But your comments answers restricting the access from AD and this is  allowed only VS online paid customers.I am using free 5 user limits. And also I want this restriction from from my VM firewall system based on IP

Comment: The IP Address mentioned in that link is for VSTS Hosted Build Agent, not for VSTS itself.

Answer (score 0):

VSTS **does not offer any type of IP-based filter** — so you can't do like in SQL Azure, in which you add and/or remove IPs that can access the service on Azure. About this area take a look at thie blog: [Prevent users from accessing the VSTS out of the workplace](https://www.tshooter.com.br/en/2016/06/08/avoid-that-users-access-o-vsts-of-out-of-work-environment/)

You should take a look at the official tutorial how to [Manage conditional access to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/manage-conditional-access?view=vsts)

> Conditional access offers simple ways to help secure resources for
>   VSTS accounts backed by an Azure Active Directory (AAD) tenant.
>   Conditional access policies like multi-factor authentication can help
>   protect against the risk of compromised credentials and help keep your
>   organization's data safe. For example, in addition to requiring
>   credentials, you can have a policy that only devices connected to a
>   corporate network can gain access.